# How to output command not finished in php?

Tags: java, php, html

I compiled a c file (name.c) and named it name.o. This is it output :

```
Hello Michael
Hello Marie
Hello Michael
Hello George
Hello Marie
Hello Man
Hello Michael
...
```

I want to output these in a php, i made it and it works great :

```
<?php 
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("./name.o", 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    $a = fread($proc, 1);;
    echo "$a";
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The only problem is that is will be very long so I would like only one line that say "Hello nameoftheperson" and not every new line.

I excepted this output :

```html
Hello Michael
```

after a second or less :

```html
Hello Marie
```

So I don't want it show the previous line.

How can I do it ? Do I have do it in Java ? (I never code in Java but if I have to ...)

Comment: So You want to prit just the first line? You can do this using `./name.o | head -n 1`.

Comment: Could you post expected output as well?

Comment: No, I just want it replace the previous line by the new line and show the changes.

Comment: I edit my first post.